# How do I order a list and add position to its items on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, list, sorting

I'm creating a Leaderboard system using MongoDB, so, I would like to know if its possible for me to get the position of a document in a list and its neighbords.

```
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_341c88077d", "value": 140 },
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_6fd772cb84", "value": 160 },
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_73bdbb334f", "value": 180 },
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_e16345075c", "value": 170 },
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_5902274617", "value": 220 }
```

I have a list similar with this one, and my goal is to have a result similar with this when I try to find `{'name': "user_73bdbb334f"}`

```
{ "position": 3, "_id": null, "name": "user_e16345075c", "value": 170 },
{ "position": 4, "_id": null, "name": "user_73bdbb334f", "value": 180 },
{ "position": 5, "_id": null, "name": "user_5902274617", "value": 220 }
```

is it possible to do something like this with MongoDB?

Comment: do you want to achieve it with a single query? I'm afraid that's not possible. But with two queries you can do that.

Comment: Doesn't need to be in just a single query, it's possible to use more than 1.

Comment: where are you going to process the query?

Comment: My idea is to save the score of the user into the database and get back the current position. So, its going to be at least 2 queries, 1 to save the data, and the other one to get the position.

Comment: I mean where are you going to execute the query, e.g. mongo shell, any driver?

Comment: I'm using nodejs and Mongoose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78693/discussion-between-n9code-and-sharbelfs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the documents enumerated with `position` right from MongoDB. Thus that your manual job to do. The second problem is getting the neighbours. If you knew in advance the position of the required document, say `i`, you could do just `.skip(i - 1).limit(3)`, and would get your neighbours with the document in the middle. The only way to know the position of your document is to sort the cursor and then calculate the number of documents appearing before the required document, which could be achieved using `.count()`. But your problem here is that several users might have the same score, so you cannot determine which of the same-scored documents is the required one.

The only way to do in this case is the following:

- get the score of required user, say `user_score`
- then get count of documents with `{score: {$lt: user_score}}`, say `less_count`
- then get count of documents with `{score: user_score, name: {$lt: "user_xxx"}}`, say `eq_count`
- then accumulate `total = less_count + eq_count + 1`, `1` for the neighbour
- then get the {score: {$lte: user_score}, name: {$lte: "user_xxx"}} documents, sort by {score: 1, name: 1}, and then `.skip(total -1).limit(3)`

But this is total 4 queries, and I think you should better go with the manual approach.

So here is a JavaScript way snippet I suggest for your goal:

```
range = 1;  # The range of neighbours to show from each side
currentIndex = 1;
meIndex = -1;  # The position of the required username

db.pos.find()
      .sort({value: 1})
      .map(function(doc) {
              doc.position = currentIndex;
              if (doc._id == username) {
                 meIndex = currentIndex
              } 
              currentIndex++; 
              return doc;
           }
      )
      .filter(function(el, i, arr) {
                 return (meIndex != -1 && Math.abs(meIndex - el.position) <= range)
              }
      )
```

First you enumerate your documents, and at the same time find the required document, and then filter out and leave only the required document and its neighbours.

**UPDATE**

By the way, you cannot have `null` as `_id` value for all documents, as it is a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Design document some thing like this,

```
{ "_id": null, "name": "user_2", "value": 140, neighbords: {up: "user_1", down: "user_3"}, pos: 2 }
```

To get position of document either keep a variable in it or `sort` based on some field and take `count` with `<` or `>` query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method of the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor to iterate over the collection, sort the result on the value key and add an extra property on the document position which holds the incremented integer value in the loop.

Firstly, you may want to consider adding an index on the value key for better performance (if you haven't already done so):

```
db.leaderboard.ensureIndex({"value": 1});
```

The following operation will then add the extra position field to your documents:

```
var index = 1;
db.leaderboard.find().sort({"value": 1}).forEach(function (doc){
    doc.position = index;
    index++;
    db.leaderboard.save(doc);
})
```